# Microsoft Graph API: ad permission to SharePoint file for a sharepoint group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

i want to add a permission to a file on sharepoint online using the Microsoft Graph API.
the special thing is that i want to grant permission to the sharepoint group "visitors of ".

i think the possibility using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http is not successful.

thanks everyone

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

tried this with different recipients and roles.

Comment: I am trying to do the same. Drive.Items("...").Permissions.Request.AddAsync isn't working.

Comment: hi,i just found outm that the Requestor with alias works.

Comment: I got it working with new DriveRecipient {ObjectId = [id of the group]}.

Comment: how did you read the id of the group? special way or just going to the group list?